# Setting the Alias Target in Route53 to an single EC2 with an IPv4 Address

Tags: dns, amazon-route53

I wanted to create an Alias record that simply points my naked domain name (zone apex) to a simple elastic IP address associated with a single EC2 instance. But that type of target isn't valid. It looks like the Alias Record targets are only limited to

1. Elastic Load Balancers (ELB's)
2. S3-Endpoints
3. Cloudfront Distributions
4. Other DNS Record Sets.

Can anybody shed some theoretical light as to why I am unable to use the A-record to point the domain to a simple EC2 with an ip address? Thanks.

Comment: A records are for pointing to IP addresses. ALIAS can point to a name. Perhaps you want to point the ALIAS at the instance "name" `(ec2-nn-nnn-nnn-nn.us.west-1.compute.amazonaws.com)`?

Comment: The issue is with the Alias.  There's an option to "select Alias".  which is similar to CNAME.  When I selected NO ALIAS.  then I was able to enter a simple ip address and the domain name was mapped to the ip.  But another problem that I found was that while I can use the mapped domain name to load up the website, when I click on any links in the website, or login to the wordpress console, the domain name is no longer mapped, and I'm left with the IP address of the EC2.  Any ideas for how to keep the domain name BOUND to the EC2, wihtout revealing the IP address?  thanks @captncraig!

Comment: I think you are confused. You want to route traffic to an ec2 instance without revealing its' IP? That is not a thing. An ALIAS record is just a fancy way of making an A record that dynamically changes as some other name does. Maybe you want a load balancer in front of it?

Comment: Link generation also has nothing to do with dns.

Comment: I just want to associate my domain name with my EC2 Web Server.  So I can type in the domain name, and the wordpress site loads up rather than typing in the IP address of the EC2.  Basic DNS 101.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot specify an EC2 instance as the target of an Alias in Route 53.

Alias record targets can be any of [these](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html) things: API Gateway, VPC endpoints, Cloudfront, Elastic Beanstalk, Elastic Load Balancer, Global Accelerator, S3 buckets using the static website hosting feature, AppSync Domains, and other records within the same zone... but nothing else.

You could use an Alias to point to an Application Load Balancer, with a target group pointing to the EC2 instance, but that isn't the point of this question. See the comments:

> when I click on any links in the website, or login to the wordpress console, the domain name is no longer mapped, and I'm left with the IP address of the EC2

The user's web server was redirecting visitors to the server's IP address when links were clicked.  This was misdiagnosed as being related to the lack of an alias.

> Basic DNS 101

Yes.  Create an A record containing the IP address of your instance.  It isn't an alias, and it shouldn't be an alias.

Your issue is that your web server itself or Wordpress is misconfigured and is actively issuing redirects to what it wrongly believes to be the correct/desired name, which has nothing to do with how this A record is provisioned.  Review your response headers and you will find a `30x` HTTP response coming from your web server.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the configuration of anything on the system.  This is related to the configuration of the Route53 zone itself (which allows for transparently synthesizing `A` records using an alias of an AWS resource as opposed to an `ALIAS` record).  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html